# Caling program across (ana)conda environments

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am using Python 3.5 for my programming, because I need a bridge to Matlab, which does not support the current Python 3.x. This is a bit annoying. Also, I would like to use http://www.optimojoe.com/products/optizelle/ which only supports Python 2.7.x. Both issues prompt me to ask the following question. With conda: Can I build my program in one conda environment with a specific Python version, e.g. Python 3.7, and call a different program which lives in a different conda environment, e.g. Python 2.7, from my program?

Comment: make a python system call with another python. I do that all the time: `subprocess.run(["/full/path/to/other/python","script.py","arg1"])`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thanks for the idea! But how can I pass complex objects between the two programs (e.g. numpy arrays and the like) without sacraficing a lot of speed and convenience? Only a write to disk comes to mind, which seems unacceptable to me due to the lack of speed. For R there is at least the rpy2-package - maybe a similar bridge from python to python exists?

Comment: yes, that's an issue. You just have to make sure that your processing lasts long enough so it's worth writing to disk.

Comment: I just happened to read this post, and thought maybe recent experience I've had might be helpful.  We're a Java and Python shop.  We've limited each of those environments to pretty separate domains until just recently.  We're now starting to want to drive low-level Java code from Python at the high level.  We're doing this quite sucessfully with Redis and JSON serialization.  Redis gives you this nice middle ground...it's much faster than writing (directly) to disk, and yet it's about as robust.  You still incur the cost of de/serialization, but it opens up a world of possibilities.

Comment: ...and we're using AWS Elasticache, so we haven't incurred any significant up front cost in going this way.  With Elasticache, you just fill out a screen with basic information, and you have a robust Redis cluster with no real effort. - of course, RPC also works (REST, etc.).  Maybe none of this applies here.  Just wanted to offer my $.02

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Indeed I would make many "small" calls to the other program.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for the suggestion. Seems like quite a bit of technological overhead though. My two cents for you: As Python-Java-bridge I used https://www.py4j.org/ very successfully. I find it odd that there are bridges for everything except for Python to Python...